# What are best practices in backend architecture of a web application?

Tags: database, web-applications, server, architecture, backend

I'm looking for best practices in backend architecture of a web application. The one I use is straightforward: websocket server on Node.js processes all client requests and saves/loads necessary information by means of MongoDB. But there are obvious problems:

1. Data storage layer. If we have only one database, it can be corrupted somehow and the data will be lost or inaccessible. So we should have several databases on different hosts and synchronize these databases, so that they have the same data. As far as I know, MongoDB has no such master-master synchronization and one should use CouchDB for example. But maybe there are some other techniques or tools?
2. Processing layer. If we have only one server, it can be inaccessible or be overloaded with too many requests. So we should have several servers on different hosts. How these servers should choose databases to interact with? Should they write to all databases or only to one (and some process will synchronize that one database with the others)?
3. Load balancing. If we have many servers for processing client requests, we must distribute the requests among the servers. As far as I know, Nginx can be used in this case. But wouldn't it be the single point of failure? Or should we use several Nginx servers?
4. Suppose we have mobile app. In this case we can't change the top layer configuration without releasing the corresponding new app version for clients. For example, if we add more servers, we should add their addresses to the client part. Is there any way of reducing such client-side changes? I can only think of the same approach with a fixed number of Nginx servers that are assumed to be unchanged.

This problem seems to be well known but I couldn't find any thorough overview on it. There are so many webapps - there must be some common solutions. Maybe there are some frameworks/libs to tackle it (found only [cote.js](http://cote.js.org/))? Maybe there are some books/articles on the topic?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).